# Vuejs mounted hook in component not working as expected

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm using mounted hook in component and want to load chart on dashboard view as you can see below.

*Dashboard script*

```
export default {
    name: 'Dashboard',
    mounted() {

        console.log(this.$el); //--> console output -> empty
        const self = this;
        this.$nextTick(function () {
            // some init codes for chart implementation
            console.log(self.$el); //--> console output -> empty also.
        }
    }
}
```

I have an App.vue file for use as container. It has default template structure (nothing has special I mean).
How to understand component loaded ?

I think; `mounted()` hook triggered when `App.vue` is loaded. But still dashboard component DOM is not created at this time. So I decided to use `nextTick` event. But it also act like `mounted()` hook. I'm bit confused.

Edit : This problem caused when `F5` button pressed on keyboard.

Edit 2: 
App.vue

```
<template>
    <section id="app" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="content">
            <router-view />
        </div>
    </section>
</template>
```

router.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Dashboard from './views/Dashboard.vue'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    { path: '/', component: Dashboard }
  ]
})
```

Comment: have you registered the child component ? 

can you provide the complete code for that component and the parent component

Comment: @mooga edited my question with code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

`this` in nextTick function is not Vue component.
You can try using arrow function

```
this.$nextTick(() => {
    // some init codes for chart implementation
    console.log(this.$el); 
}
```

or closure:

```
var self = this
this.$nextTick(() => {
    // some init codes for chart implementation
    console.log(self.$el); 
}
```

Comment: Oh, thanks for the correction. But still it's null in `nextTick`.

Comment: Do you have `<template>` tag in your Vue component?

Comment: absolutely yes. If not exist component doesn't work.